# WooCommerce custom checkout verification not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to make a second (first) checkout verification. For this job I need to prevent the standard WooCommerce checkout verification. I've did this with a lot of forms before but this time the trigger don't responds.

**What I expect:**

When the user clicks the Place Order button, the standard WooCommerce checkout verification should not run and the browser alerts my text.

**What happens:**

When I click the button, I don't see any text/alert.

**My code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var checkoutForm = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-checkout');
    var postcode = jQuery('#billing_postcode', checkoutForm);

    if (checkoutForm != null) {
        checkoutFormValidation(checkoutForm, postcode);
    }
});

function checkoutFormValidation(checkoutForm, postcode) {

    var checkoutButton = checkoutForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
}
```

I've checked everything and the file is included at the checkout. So no idea why this don't works.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The problem is, that there is another validation function which gets triggered by default. So if you want to just add a custom validation without loosing the WooCommerce validation, you can't do it the way I've tried. So the solution is to use the WooCommerce validation function:

```
jQuery(document.body).on("checkout_error", function () {
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```